# showing data from mysql database in table

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to take data from a my database and echo it in a table with php, but when I upload my code to my server and execute it, I just get a blank space. What have I done wrong?

```
<?php 
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "economics";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM Points";

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Alexis'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Anthony'] . "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Mixing MySQL APIs. If you don't know what that means, Google it. *Frankly,* I'm getting a bit tired of constantly saying this. I think I'll setup an automatic message for questions like these.

Comment: Blank screen? Try to see PHP errors. Try to see them in logs, or turn the error reporting on to see them.  You connect to `mysqi` but query `mysql_` functions, which is totally separate and different things

Comment: Thank you, This was a stupid mistake. I changed all the code to an oldskool mysql type, but this actually didn't solve the problem, It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

first off, you are creating an sqli connection, but are trying to to use sql to fetch array:  `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` maybe try changing this to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` and `$result = mysql_query($query);` to `$result = mysqli_query($query);`. This might help. also change the end to `mysqli_close`.

Comment: You're welcome. However, `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_close()` require a DB connection be passed as the first parameter. Yet, OP is using object oriented style to connect with, so the query will be a bit different.

Comment: I usually end up using pdo instead of mysqli, so naturally there is going to be a difference between what I know and what should work. I do know that you cannot mix code from mysql, mysqli or pdo as they are three totally different ways of creating sql connections.

Comment: Thank you, This was a stupid mistake. I changed all the code to an oldskool mysql type, but this actually didn't solve the problem, It still doesn't work